# 'Busy' gif while process is running in Python Shiny. When are Python Shiny reactive values checked?

Tags: python, py-shiny

I am trying to have a spinning wheel displayed in my app while a process is running.
However, I don't have a good understanding on how reactivity is functionning in Shiny. Is there a thread checking the reactive values at all time? Is there a waiting list of functions and, if so, when and how are they executed?

Here is a simplified version of what I did and which is not working as the `ui_waiting_wheel` function is executed only when `result_text` is over.

```
import time
from pathlib import Path
from shiny import App, reactive, render, ui

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_action_button("compute_button", "COMPUTE"),
    ui.output_ui('ui_waiting_wheel'),
    ui.output_text("result_text"),
)

def server(input, output, session):
    is_loading_result = reactive.Value(False)

    @output
    @render.text
    def ui_waiting_wheel():
        if is_loading_result():
            return ui.HTML('<img src="spinning-wheel-mozo.gif" alt="This is an animated gif image"/>')
        return None


    @output
    @render.text
    @reactive.event(input.compute_button, ignore_none=True)
    def result_text():
        is_loading_result.set(True)
        time.sleep(2)
        is_loading_result.set(False)
        return 'finished'

www_dir = Path(__file__).parent / "www"
app = App(app_ui, server, static_assets=www_dir)
```